# Difference of two algebraic integers is itself an integer.

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am reading up on algebraic integers and their role as solutions to monic polynomials of degree $n$ with integer coefficients. I know that it is true that not all algebraic integers can be expressed or constructed as sums of radical expressions. However, my question is if we are given two algebraic integers whose difference is itself an integer (natural number), does that mean those algebraic integers are expressible in terms of radical expressions, or at least simple mathematical expressions such as addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division? I.E. is it possible to define those numbers in terms of an integer part and an irrational part?

Comment: Strictly speaking, you allow them to be the same (the difference to be $0$). Even without that, if $\alpha$ is a solution of a quintic such that it cannot be expressed via radicals (and rest assured that the quintic can be chosen to be monic), then $\alpha-k$ is again not expressible in radicals, for any $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

No: take $\alpha$ and $\alpha+1$, where $\alpha$ is any algebraic integer not expressible "simply" (hence $\alpha+1$ will also be an algebraic integer not expressible "simply").